# Multiple socket.io connections in angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, web, socket.io, chat

So I’m working on a project in angular and I’m passing data to and from node using socket io.

Part of the application is a chat and I’m working on getting a count of currently online users.

As many parts of the app require a socket io connection, I open them in multiple services. This has started to cause an issue when working out online users as I receive multiple disconnects presumably from the multiple times I open a connection.
Is there a better way to approach this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper way to handle websockets in angular is to manage them through a service. You probably want a `SocketService` which manages the socket and attach various other services for your use cases, for example a `ChatService`. For example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {environment} from 'environments/environment';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {

  private socket;

  constructor() {
  }

  connect(token: string): Subject<MessageEvent> {
    this.socket = io(environment.socketUrl, {
      query: {token}
    });

    // We define our observable which will observe any incoming messages
    // from our socket.io server.
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log('Received message from Websocket Server');
        observer.next(data);
      });

      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      }
    });

    // We define our Observer which will listen to messages
    // from our other components and send messages back to our
    // socket server whenever the `next()` method is called.
    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        this.socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(data));
      },
    };

    // we return our Rx.Subject which is a combination
    // of both an observer and observable.
    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }
}
```

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {WebsocketService} from './WebsocketService';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {

  messages$: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private wsService: WebsocketService) {
  }

  connect(token) {
    this.messages$ = <Subject<any>>this.wsService
      .connect(token)
      .map((response: any): any => {
        return response;
      });
  }

  sendMsg(msg) {
    this.messages$.next(msg);
  }
}
```

Since services in angular are usually singleton, you'll end up with one connection per service.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Not sure how id handle this on the server side. Sorry, pretty new to socket io